# TikZ non standard shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I am trying to figure out how to generate this in tikz so I can embed in my LaTeX document. Most drawing I have are following variation of a theme. For actual text, I use Indic language in my TeX document. See below:

[image: patterns]

[image: more patterns]

Some early attempts for other shapes:

```
    % circle 4: The Hexad

  \coordinate (O6) at (4,0);
  \def\rad{1.5}
  \def\radi{0.75}
  \node (origin) at (4,0) []{};
  \draw[line width=1pt] (origin) circle (\rad);
  \draw[line width=1pt] (origin) circle (\radi);

  \pgfmathsetmacro{\HexA}{90}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\HexB}{30}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\HexC}{330}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\HexD}{270}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\HexE}{210}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\HexF}{150}
  \path (O6) +(\HexA:\rad) coordinate (A6);
  \path (O6) +(\HexB:\rad) coordinate (B6);
  \path (O6) +(\HexC:\rad) coordinate (C6);
  \path (O6) +(\HexD:\rad) coordinate (D6);
  \path (O6) +(\HexE:\rad) coordinate (E6);
  \path (O6) +(\HexF:\rad) coordinate (F6);

  \path (O6) +(\HexA:\radi) coordinate (A61);
  \path (O6) +(\HexB:\radi) coordinate (B61);
  \path (O6) +(\HexC:\radi) coordinate (C61);
  \path (O6) +(\HexD:\radi) coordinate (D61);
  \path (O6) +(\HexE:\radi) coordinate (E61);
  \path (O6) +(\HexF:\radi) coordinate (F61);

  \fill[black] (A6) circle[radius=0pt] ++(\HexA:2mm) node {\large \sanskritunicode pe};
  \fill[black] (B6) circle[radius=0pt] ++(\HexB:2mm) node {\large \sanskritunicode śa};
  \fill[black] (C6) circle[radius=0pt] ++(\HexC:2mm) node {\large \sanskritunicode ce};
  \fill[black] (D6) circle[radius=0pt] ++(\HexD:2mm) node {\large \sanskritunicode mo};
  \fill[black] (E6) circle[radius=0pt] ++(\HexE:2mm) node {\large \sanskritunicode na};
  \fill[black] (F6) circle[radius=0pt] ++(\HexF:2mm) node {\large \sanskritunicode cū};

  \draw[line width=1pt] (A6) -- (A61);
  \draw[line width=1pt] (B6) -- (B61);
  \draw[line width=1pt] (C6) -- (C61);
  \draw[line width=1pt] (D6) -- (D61);
  \draw[line width=1pt] (E6) -- (E61);
  \draw[line width=1pt] (F6) -- (F61);
```

Comment: Welcome! Please show us what you have so far. It is easier to help if we know where you are stuck! It is also going to be important to see how you are setting up the language stuff e.g. are you using `fontspec`? `polyglossia`? XeTeX? LuaTeX? Presumably you can draw the circles OK. Are the segments problematic? Or the partial arcs in the first set? In order to help you draw them, we need to see how you are trying to do it.

Comment: A few of these are circles and arcs, bus most can simply be drawn as curved lines using to[] to connect points.

Comment: I could draw the simpler shapes - which were like concentric circles with similar markings. This is xelatex using polyglossia. No problems with any fonts.

Comment: i am unable to add the image file because no more than 2 images could be posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possibility for the first shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\FirstShape[2]{%
% The basic shape
\draw 
  (70:4) arc(70:275:4) -- 
  (270:3) arc(270:75:3) -- 
  (70:4) to[out=-90,in=110] 
  (45:2) to[out=-120,in=110]
  (0:1.5) to[out=-120,in=110]
  (-50:2) to[out=-130,in=80]
  (275:4) --
  (270:3) to[out=80,in=-130]
  (-60:1.3) to[out=110,in=-120]
  (20:0.85) to[out=110,in=-120]
  (60:1.8) to[out=110,in=-90]
  (75:3)
  (45:2) -- (60:1.8)
  (0:1.5) -- (20:0.85)
  (-50:2) -- (-60:1.3);
% The numbers inside
\foreach \Value [evaluate=\Value as \Step using {\Value*200/#1} ] in  {1,...,#1}
  { 
    \ifdim\dimexpr275pt-\Step pt\relax=75 pt\relax
    \else
      \draw  ({275-\Step}:4) -- ++(275-\Step:-1);
      \node at ({275-\Step}:2.7) {\the\numexpr\Value+1\relax};
    \fi
  }  
\node[left] at (270:2.7) {1};
\node[left] at (73:2.7) {\the\numexpr#1+1\relax};
\node[left=2pt] at (60:1.8) {\the\numexpr#1+2\relax};
\node[left=2pt] at (20:0.85) {\the\numexpr#1+3\relax};
\node[left=2pt] at (-60:1.3) {\the\numexpr#1+4\relax};
% The texts outside
\foreach \Text [count=\Value,evaluate=\Value as \Step using {\Value*200/#1} ] in  {#2}
  \node at ({275-\Step}:4.5) {\Text}; 
\foreach \Text [
  count=\Value,
  evaluate=\Value as \Step using {\Value*200/#1} 
  ] in  {#2}
  {
    \node at ({275-\Step}:4.5) {\Text};
  }
% The constant texts in the right part
\node[right=2pt] at (70:4) {text1};
\node[right=2pt] at (45:2) {text2};
\node[right=2pt] at (0:1.5) {text3};
\node[right=2pt] at (-50:2) {text4};
\node[below=2pt] at (270:4) {text5};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\FirstShape{2}{texta}
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\FirstShape{3}{texta,textb}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\FirstShape{4}{texta,textb,textc}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end {document}
```

[image]

## Explanation

All the job is done by a `\FirstShape` command with two mandatory arguments:

```
\FirstShape{<number>}{<texts>}
```

where  is an integer indicating the number of subdivisions of the "half circle" to the left and  is a comma separated list of the texts for the "half circle" to the left. All the other elements are placed automatically.

Here's one take at the second shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%Draw the outer circle
\draw (0,0) circle (4);
% Draw the inner curved arcs
% First, from 260 to 160 degrees; second, from 170 to 45,
% third, from 45 to -45, last, from -45 to -100
\foreach \Start/\End in {260/170,170/45,45/-45,-45/-100}
\draw[rounded corners=10pt]
  (\Start:4) -- ++(\Start:-1) arc(\Start:\End:3) -- (\End:4);
% drawing the subdivisions for each curved portion
% For the portion between 260 and 170
\begin{scope}
\clip[rounded corners=10pt]
  (260:4) -- ++(260:-1) arc(260:170:3) -- (170:4) arc(170:260:4) ;
\foreach \Value in {240,217.5,192.5}
  \draw (\Value:4) -- ++(\Value:-1);
\end{scope}
% For the portion between 170 and 45
\begin{scope}
\clip[rounded corners=10pt]
  (170:4) -- ++(170:-1) arc(170:45:3) -- (45:4) arc(45:170:4) ;
\foreach \Value in {85,125}
  \draw (\Value:4) -- ++(\Value:-1);
\end{scope}
% For the portion between 45 and -45
\begin{scope}
\clip[rounded corners=10pt]
  (45:4) -- ++(45:-1) arc(45:-45:3) -- (-45:4) arc(-45:45:4) ;
\draw (0:4) -- ++(0:-1);
\end{scope}
% For the portion between -45 and -100
\begin{scope}
\clip[rounded corners=10pt]
  (-45:4) -- ++(-45:-1) arc(-45:-100:3) -- (-100:4) arc(-100:-45:4);
\foreach \Value in {-58,-70,-85}
  \draw (\Value:4) -- ++(\Value:-1);
\end{scope}
% Placing the labels in the outer circle
\foreach \Value/\Text in {260/a,240/b,217.5/c,192.5/d,170/e,125/f,85/g,45/h,0/i,-45/j,-58/k,-70/l,-85/m}
   \node at (\Value:4.2) {\Text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo Medina. I have enough to develop. Some of the original drawings were not done symmetrically (due to limitations) and are from old texts.

Comment: Trying to figure out how those angles were derived in each of the foreach loop, so that I can apply similar logic in other diagrams. The drawing have a pattern of drawing two concentric circles/polygons, with some edges that are curved

Comment: @jayr The main part of the code is `\draw (0,0) circle (4);
\foreach \Start/\End in {260/170,170/45,45/-45,-45/-100}
\draw[rounded corners=10pt]
  (\Start:4) -- ++(\Start:-1) arc(\Start:\End:3) -- (\End:4);`. This draws the outer circle and the inner ones with rounded corners. One "portion" will go from 270 to 160 (degrees); the second, from 170 to 45, the third, from 45 to -45 and the last one from -45 to -100. The other part of the code is just to draw the divisions for each segment; unfortunately the code there is longer since some clipping has to be done.

Comment: @jayr I added some comments to the code explaining what each part does.

Comment: I played with the angles and see their correspondence. How is the expression 
\draw[rounded corners=10pt] (\Start:4) -- ++(\Start:-1) arc(\Start:\End:3) -- (\End:4) 
to be interpreted

Comment: @jayr It uses polar coordinates: Let's assume the first iteration of the loop, in which `\Start=260` and `\End=170`. Begin at `(260:4)` (which means 4 units away from the origin at an angle of 260) go to `(260:3)` draw an arc starting at 260, ending at 170 with a radius of 3 and then end at `(170:4)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29625/discussion-between-jayr-and-gonzalo-medina).